# distinct pairs of indices from two 1d tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two discrete probability distributions. These are represented as TensorFlow 1D tensors `p1` and `p2`, each of length `len`. I want to generate pairs of indices `(i, j)`, where `i` is generated from the first probability distribution and `j` is from the second. I want to generate a lot of pairs until there are in total `len` distinct pairs. How can I achieve this in TensorFlow using a while loop or scan?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicate, one might first start by removing duplicates from the 1d tensors p1 and p2

```py
p1 = tf.unique(tf.constant([1, 2, 3]))
p2 = tf.unique(tf.constant([3, 4, 5]))
```

Computing the pairs

```py
p1 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
p2 = tf.constant([3, 4, 5])

# adding zeros columns
t1 = tf.stack([p1, tf.zeros([a.shape[0]], dtype="int32")], axis=1)
t2 = tf.stack([tf.zeros([b.shape[0]], dtype="int32"), p2], axis=1)
x = tf.expand_dims(t1, 0)
y = tf.expand_dims(t2, 1)

# broadcasting with addition to concatenate the two tensors
# reshaping to have the 2d tensor
c = tf.reshape(tf.add(x, y), [-1, 2])
```